# Unity - going to the next level when glass it's full

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d-games

I am trying to make next level availble when the glass it's full. For now the next level will unlock only when you click on the button "next level", and if you repeat the level, the next level wont be unblocked.

here is pictures for reference :

[image]

This is the locked levels script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class LockedLevels : MonoBehaviour {


    void Awake()
    {
        transform.GetChild(1).localScale = Vector3.one;
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("1", 1);

        for (int i = 0; i < transform.GetChild(1).childCount; i++)
        {
            transform.GetChild(1).GetChild(i).gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }
        UnLockLevels();

    }
    void Update()
    {
        transform.GetChild(0).gameObject.GetComponent<Text>().text = transform.name;
        transform.GetChild(0).gameObject.GetComponent<Text>().fontSize = 75;
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Delete))
        {
            PlayerPrefs.DeleteAll();
        }
    }

    public void UnLockLevels()
    {

        if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt(gameObject.name) == 1)
        {
            transform.GetChild(0).gameObject.GetComponent<Text>().color = new Color(1,1,1,1) ;
            GetComponent<Button>().interactable = true;
            if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Star" + gameObject.name) == 3)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < transform.GetChild(1).childCount; i++)
                {
                    transform.GetChild(1).GetChild(i).gameObject.SetActive(true);
                }
            }
            else if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Star" + gameObject.name) == 2)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < transform.GetChild(1).childCount-1; i++)
                {
                    transform.GetChild(1).GetChild(i).gameObject.SetActive(true);
                }
            }
            else if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Star" + gameObject.name) == 1)
            {
                transform.GetChild(1).GetChild(0).gameObject.SetActive(true);

            }
            else if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Star" + gameObject.name) == 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < transform.GetChild(1).childCount; i++)
                {
                    transform.GetChild(1).GetChild(i).gameObject.SetActive(false);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            GetComponent<Button>().interactable = false;
            transform.GetChild(0).gameObject.GetComponent<Text>().color = new Color(1, 1, 1, .5f);
        }
    }
    public void LevelMenu()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(transform.name);
    }
}
```

And this is the glassFill script :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class GlassFill : MonoBehaviour {

    int trigCont;
    GameManager gm;
    int Star;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        gm = FindObjectOfType<GameManager>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
    {
        if (col.gameObject.tag == "DynamicParticle")
        {
            if (trigCont == 0)
            {
                transform.parent.GetChild(0).GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = gm.SurpriseGlass;

            }
            col.gameObject.tag = "InGlassWater";
            col.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().gravityScale = .3f;
            col.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = col.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity /4;
            trigCont++;

            if (trigCont > 50)
            {
                if (trigCont == 51)
                {
                    if (Mathf.FloorToInt(gm.PenCapacity.value * 100) > 75)
                    {
                        Star = 3;
                    }
                    else if (Mathf.FloorToInt(gm.PenCapacity.value * 100) > 50)
                    {
                        Star = 2;
                    }
                    else if (Mathf.FloorToInt(gm.PenCapacity.value * 100) > 25)
                    {
                        Star = 1;
                    }
                    print(Star + "star");
                    transform.parent.GetChild(0).GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = gm.HappyGlass;
                    Camera.main.GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play();
                    Invoke("nextScene", 2);
                    CancelInvoke("Check");
                    for (int i = 0; i < Camera.main.transform.childCount; i++)
                    {
                        if (Camera.main.transform.GetChild(i).GetComponent<ParticleSystem>() != null)
                        {
                            Camera.main.transform.GetChild(i).GetComponent<ParticleSystem>().Play();
                        }
                    }
                }               
            }
            else
            {
                CancelInvoke("Check");
                Invoke("Check",5);
            }
            if (trigCont > 60)
            {                                               //You can write  a function over here if you want to give a star according to glass fill
                print("two star");
            }           
            if (trigCont > 70)
            {
                print("three star");
            }
        }
    }
    void Check()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex);
    }
    void nextScene()
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt((SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex).ToString(), 1);
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Star" + SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name, Star);
        gm.LevComp.SetActive(true);
        if (Star > 2)
        {
            gm.LevComp.transform.GetChild(0).gameObject.SetActive(true);
            gm.LevComp.transform.GetChild(1).gameObject.SetActive(true);
            gm.LevComp.transform.GetChild(2).gameObject.SetActive(true);
        } 
        else if (Star > 1)
        {
            gm.LevComp.transform.GetChild(0).gameObject.SetActive(true);
            gm.LevComp.transform.GetChild(1).gameObject.SetActive(true);
        }
        else if (Star>0)
        {
            gm.LevComp.transform.GetChild(0).gameObject.SetActive(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to  show your object heirarchy and also which objects the `GlassFill` and `LockedLevels` are attached to. (screenshots preferable but text may be ok too)

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume you have an empty gameobject named levelManagerGO in your scene which contains the script LockedLevels. I believe the method which needs to be invoked is `UnLockLevels()`. So you should create a reference inside your script GlassFill to the empty gameobject containing LockedLevels, so you can invoke `UnLockLevels()`.

```
levelManagerGO.Invoke("UnLockLevels", 0f);
```

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Invoke.html

Answer (score 0):

One way to check if the glass is full, could be to make many small child objects of the glass. Each of them having a collider. If all, or a certain percentage of, the child objects then are in contact with some kind of water. Then you will know that the glass is full and you can proceed to the next level. You can run this check maybe once per second.

Just have a list of each of those childobjects and check their status once per second or so.

Comment: and how do i do that?

Comment: do what? Add the objects to a list?